# Gatsby build NODE_ENV error: Conflicting values for 'process.env.NODE_ENV'

Tags: npm, environment-variables, gatsby

I have a `.env.development`, `.env.staging`, and a `.env.production` file in my gatsby project. I obviously want to reference a different file in a each environment and have the following code at the top of my `gatsby-congif.js` file to do so:

```
if ((process.env.NODE_ENV = 'staging')) {
  // use the .env.staging environment file
  require('dotenv').config({
    path: `.env.staging`,
  });
} else {
  // fallback to default Gatsby .env handling for development or production
  require('dotenv').config({
    paths: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
  });
}
```

I have the following relevant scripts in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "gatsby develop",
    "stage": "NODE_ENV=staging gatsby build",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    ...
  },
```

If I do `npm run stage`, the `NODE_ENV` variable is set to `staging` and it seems to work well. But, if I switch back and run `npm run build`, the `NODE_ENV` variable is still set to `staging`. I know that Gatsby sets it to `production` by default when you run `npm run build` so I'm confused about why it is not resetting. I am also getting this warning when I run `npm run build`:

```
warn DefinePlugin
Conflicting values for 'process.env.NODE_ENV'
```

Anyone know how to force `NODE_ENV` back to `production` when I run `npm run build`?